# Mock chrome.storage API with Playwright

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, playwright

My program is using `chrome.storage` to [store and access data from the user](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/). I'm using Playwright to test my program. I'm trying to mock `chrome.storage.sync.get`, because right now it's returning an empty object and so my program does not work properly in this test environment.

This is my Playwright code:

```js
test('MyTest', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.myWebsite.com/');
  ...
  const result = page.locator("#data"); // This depends on the value stored in chrome.storage
  await expect(result).toContainText('storedData');
});
```

The following code in my program is used to fetch the user's data and create the element which is tested by Playwright.

```js
const result = await chrome.storage.sync.get("data") // result = 'storedData'
const myDiv= document.createElement("div")
myDiv.id = 'data'
myDiv.textContent = result.data
```

I've tried mocking using [Playwright's Mock browser APIs](https://playwright.dev/docs/mock-browser-apis). But it does not mock the function, since it's only returning an empty object.

```js
await page.addInitScript(() => {
  const mock = {
    data: 'storedData'
  }
  // Supposed to mock chrome.storage.sync.get
  chrome.storage.sync.get = async () => mock ;
});
```

I've also tried with `channel: 'chrome'` and running the script with a local version of Chrome Canary. Both of these didn't resolve the problem.

I'm running the tests inside chromium with Playwright Version 1.36.1.
I'm using [a fixture for web extension](https://playwright.dev/docs/chrome-extensions).

Comment: Did you try setting the [channel](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-use-options#other-options) to chrome. So you can use Chrome instead of Chromium.

Comment: @hardkoded Thanks for the suggestion. The problem I had `chrome is undefined` was because I was using the function inside Playwright, which is not an instance of chrome. This has been resolved. Now, I'm still not able to mock `chrome.storage.sync.get`. I've updated my question to reflect my situation.